# leaflet-control-search search for dynamically added markers

Tags: javascript, search, openstreetmap, leaflet

i'm using leaflet-control-search to search for markers. The markers are stored in an array like this

```
var mymarkers = [{"loc": [lat,lng], "name": "a"},{"loc": [lat,lng], "name": "b"}];
```

I'm looping in this array to put it in a layerGroup called "markersLayer".
Since its only possible  to search one layergroup in leaflet-control-search i'm dynamically adding/removing markers in "markersLayer".

search-control is being initialized like this

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({layer: markersLayer, propertyName: "name", circleLocation:true});
```

When i add markers in "markersLayer", and search for a marker it shows me this marker by circling it. When i remove my markers and put it back in "markersLayer" leaflet-control-search no longer circles a marker when i search for it.

Then i thought maybe i can open a popup on that found marker instead. theres an event called 'search_locationfound'. so i tried:

```
searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function(e) {

    e.marker.openPopup();

});
```

but nothing happens. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: nvm, i got it working with e.layer as its a LayerEvent.. also e.marker doesnt exist,